# MongoDB, Windows 7, XAMPP, PHP.ini

Tags: php, apache, codeigniter, mongodb, xampp

I am having a lot of trouble getting XAMPP to work with MongoDB on Windows 7.

I'm using XAMPP 1.7.7/PHP 5.3.8.

I have MongoDB setup properly and can query via a shell (and MongoD.exe is running).

But whenever I try to access MongoDB via a PHP script, I get the error (via CodeIgniter):

> The MongoDB PECL extension has not been installed or enabled

It does NOT show MongoDB in the extensions when I run phpinfo().  However, I've used the drivers located here https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-driver/downloads and added the appropriate lines to php.ini

It seems to me that the server isn't actually reading php.ini.  I have tried every version of the 5.3 driver in that zip file and it never loads.  There are also no errors in the PHP error log OR the Apache error log.

phpinfo() says it's using the following php.ini files:

```
> Configuration File (php.ini) Path C:\Windows 
> Loaded Configuration File C:\xampp\php\php.ini
```

There is NOT a php.ini file in C:\Windows.  The only php.ini that exists on my machine is in C:\xampp\php\php.ini and modifying it seems to have absolutely no effect.  Even if I put extension=norealfilename.abc, it doesn't throw an error, which seems odd.

I'm totally at a loss here and I've lost several days trying to get this going and am beyond frustrated.  Any help would be appreciated.

Other relevant phpinfo() information:
System  Windows NT MY-PC 6.1 build 7601 (Windows 7 Home Premium Edition Service Pack 1) i586
Compiler    MSVC9 (Visual C++ 2008)
Architecture    x86
Thread Safety   enabled

If you need more information let me know and I will update this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did the following (to use with Codeigniter):

Downloaded from https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-driver/downloads

*Careful to get the thread-safe version.

Then add this line in your php.ini file:

> extension=php_mongo-1.2.11-5.3-vc9-x86_64.dll (or whatever version did you download)

Then restart your server and check the error log to see if there are any errors/conflicts.

PS: I use WAMP!

Comment: Those are the drivers I used.  I tried that one specifically again to be thorough, but no dice.  No errors reported to either log and still no Mongo extension listed in phpinfo().

Comment: I never used XAMPP though..can you check with a fresh wamp install? it should work fine.

Comment: I was reluctant to do this because it didn't actually fix the problem I was having, but a clean install of WAMP with the same Mongo drivers did the trick.  Oh well, it works.

Comment: @can u able to solve this question i am in hurry, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30910162/unable-to-load-dynamic-library-php-mongo-1-6-8-5-6-vc11-dll-in-php

Answer (score 1):

After testing several builds, the one which worked for me was: php_mongo-1.3.1-5.3-vc9-x86_64.dll from this package. http://cloud.github.com/downloads/mongodb/mongo-php-driver/php_mongo-1.3.1.zip
My environment:
Windows 8 64 bits x64 based processor.
Winginx Php 5.3.8